# Can rework Galio E pass through non-terrain walls?

Tags: league-of-legends

Galio rework is going to hit live soon. I don't have access to PBE to test the skills;
 Will someone confirm if Anivia wall (or Trundle pillar, Jarvan ult, Taliyah ult, etc) can block the Galio E: Justice Punch on release patch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Galio's new E ability (Justice Punch) is explicitly designed to be *unable to travel through walls*. This is because Galio is meant to be an initiation-style tank character - running away is counter to his theme.

From the [official reveal](https://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/champion-galio-the-colossus):

> Galio hops back to wind up for an epic haymaker. After a brief delay, he charges forward, dealing magic damage to enemies and knocking them up. Galio's charge stops upon colliding with a champion **or terrain**.

Since player-created terrain such as an Anivia wall or Trundle pillar does count as terrain, Galio should be unable to pass through it.

You can see the punch in action, as well as its interaction with terrain, in the [official champion spotlight on Youtube](https://youtu.be/t3BFQMW2Lfw).

Comment: Thank you. While I am aware it won't pass through map terrain, is there any source on it being unable to pass through champion-created obstacles?

Comment: Player created terrain counts as terrain, so he should still be unable to travel through it.

Comment: Vayne's tumble can't go through terrain, but can still get out of Jarvan's ult. I wouldn't be so sure about this without actually testing it. Bard's magical journey also doesn't work on player created terrain, so it's treated differently.

Comment: @Kruga The Vayne tumble thing is a buggy interaction, not intended behavior. She can't tumble through Anivia wall or Trundle pillar, both of which are much thicker than Jarvan's ultimate. Also, her ability description doesn't explicitly say she can't travel through walls; Galio's does, which to me implies they added some extra code to ensure it happens for Galio. (You still might be able to jump out of the Jarvan ult by standing at the very edge, facing inwards, and then punching, since Galio takes a step back before the charge, which might put him outside. That's would still be a bug though.)

Comment: And the reason Bard's E doesn't work on player-created terrain is because the terrain is temporary. It wouldn't make sense if, for example, A Taliyah ulted, Bard created a path through the wall, and Taliyah cancels the wall. The path would just be floating in midair, probably causing collision errors or misclicks.

Answer (score 3):

No. From the [rework page](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/featured/champion-galio-the-colossus):

> **E: Justice Punch**
>   Galio hops back to wind up for an epic haymaker. After a brief delay, he charges forward, dealing magic damage to enemies and knocking them up. Galio's charge stops upon colliding with a champion or terrain.

I also happen to have PBE access right now, and I can confirm that this is how it works, having seen plenty of people playing Galio.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't. His E is blocked by champions and terrain. You can see more details on the [Galio rework](https://www.lol-smurfs.com/blog/galio-rework/) here.

In the upside, It'll make it super easy to find hidden Teemos!